# How do I properly import templates from HTML5 UP into django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Im trying to upload templates from HTLM5 UP into the Django framework. However I'm not sure where to place some of the supporting CSS, SASS, Webfonts, Javascript files. Link to the template I downloaded below. Files I'm referring to are in the "Assets" folder.

https://html5up.net/strata

I've tried placing them in the path below. I'm using the Pycharm IDE if that changes anything.

ProjectName/mysite/templates/mysite/assets

I've been trying to call them with href="mysite/assets/css/main.css" with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IDE: PyCharm**

At first, you need to `{% load staticfiles %}` top of the `.html` file

> And link your file like :

**CSS =** `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}" />`

**img=** `<img src="{% static 'images/rakib.jpg' %}" alt="" />`

**Js=** `<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>`

> **Full code:**

**Filename:** base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> {% block head_title %} Blog {% endblock head_title %} </title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href=href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}" />
    <style>
        {% block style %}  {% endblock style %}
    </style>

    {% block head_extra %}   {% endblock head_extra %}
</head>
```